# Условия в шаблоне Django, вывести Div только на главной

Tags: python, django

Добрый день, подскажите, пожалуйста, как вывести div в шаблоне Django  только на главной странице сайта. Мне кажется что должно быть какое-либо условие в шаблоне.

Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас сейчас один общий шаблон на все страницы?  Если да то у вас, как минимум, два варианта: дополнять(extend) базовый шаблон шаблоном для главной страницы; или контролировать контекст передаваемый именно для главной страницы.

Ссылки на тег `{% extends %}`

- [tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/templates](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/templates.html)
- [tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/template_extending](http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/template_extending/index.html)

Для более полного ответа - нужен более развернутый вопрос.

Comment: Если буквально отвечать на свой же вопрос то мне вот это подходит:             

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    ...
)


{% if request.path == "/" %}
    ...
{% endif %}      Но я ваш ответ изучу, мне кажется вы правильнее решение привели.

Comment: Как вариант можно сделать так. Но это актуально только в том случае, если у вас в будущем будет только один шаблон на весь проект.
Можно ещё добавить легкую избыточность этого решения(для вашей задачи) - при каждом запросе будет происходить передача всех данных из requestа в контекст шаблона.